# ¿como hago para imprimir el nombre en ves de lD en laravel 6? Tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-blade, laravel-6

cuando quiero implementar los datos de una operación para cada usuario no se muestra el nombre de la tabla relacionada, si no el ID

**MI BASE DE DATOS ESTA ESTRUCTURADA DE LA SIGUIENTE FORMA:**

//////////////////////////////////
operations

- id
- user_id
- beneficiary_id

//////////////////////////////////

beneficiaries

- id
- user_id
- name
  //////////////////////////////////

MIS OPERACIONES SE MUESTRA BIEN SEGÚN EL USUARIO, PERO QUIERO MOSTRAR EL NOMBRE DEL BENEFICIARIO 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el modelo

- Beneficiary
- Operation
- User

Comment: Como tienes estructurados tus modelos?

Comment: Le falta estructura e información a tu pregunta, date una vuelta por [ask]

Comment: Tengo el modelo

Beneficiary
Operation
User

Answer (score -2):

de primeras sube el codigo porfavor para que podamos ayudarte mejor, pero entiendo lo que te esta pasando.

Vete al model Operation y create una funcion name():

```
public function name($id){
  $name = Beneficiary::where('user_id', $id)->select('name')->first();
  return $name->name;
```

Y con eso lo tendrias, en tu blade donde estas pintando los datos le pasas:

```
$operation->name($operation->id)
```

Comment: Bastante innecesario de hacer así, teniendo en cuenta existencia de las relaciones de Eloquent

Comment: Por supuesto que se podrian utilizar relaciones, pero visto lo visto, creo que se le complicaria la cosa un poquito...

Comment: Qué mala respuesta, esto es lo que llaman «ingeniería excesiva o sobredimensionada».